# ansible ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, command while running

Tags: ansible

```yaml
- name: test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    #command 1
  - name: ansible-test command 1
    iosxr_command:
     commands:
     - show inventory
    when: ansible_network_os == 'iosxr'
    register: output
  - debug:
     var: output.stdout

  - name: print command executed
    hosts: 127.0.0.1
    connection: local
    command: 
    - echo sh inventory
    register: output1

  - debug:
     var: output1.stdout
```

this is my playbook

> ```
> ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, command
>
> The error appears to be in '/root/container/playbook2.yaml': line 16, column 5, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
>
>   - name: print command executed
>     ^ here
> ```

I am encountering this error.
Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: validate your yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indents.  You need to start a new play with a new set of hosts and a new task list.

```
- name: test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    #command 1
  - name: ansible-test command 1
    iosxr_command:
     commands:
     - show inventory
    when: ansible_network_os == 'iosxr'
    register: output
  - debug:
     var: output.stdout

- name: print command executed
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - command: echo sh inventory
    register: output1

  - debug:
     var: output1.stdout
```

Comment: i was previously using ansible 2.7 and was not facing this issue. now in ansible 2.9, i am. could you let me know if this is causing an issue?

Comment: No, I'm sure that is not the case.